# Yandex maps api - event handler executed only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-api

I would like to achieve something similar as `.one()`  / http://api.jquery.com/one/
with `myYandexMap.events.add('click', function(e){})` 
. That means, to have a function on click, that would only be run once or I could replace it with other function.

I have tried to remove the inner function at the end of the function, but I didn't figure out how to do it. This is basically what I've done

```
yxMap.events.add('click', function (e){ add_wp_map_click(e, num, color) });

function add_wp_map_click(e, num, color){
  ...
  yxMap.events.remove('click', function (e){ add_wp_map_click(e, num, color) });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use `.once` method as:

```
yxMap.events.once('click', handler, context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the same handler, redeclaring the function doesn't work because it are two different functions for javascript (`function() {} === function() {} -> false`).

Try:

```
var clickHandler = function(e) { 
    yxMap.events.remove('click', clickHandler);

    add_wp_blah(); 
};

yxMap.events.add('click', clickHandler);
```